# JavaFx TableView - TableColumn String Type sorted as Double Type

Tags: javafx, tableview

So I basicly have Tableview, with some columns there. One of the columns (Price) consist of Strings which actually represents Doubles. Only reason why is that, because I wanted that doubles ,for example, as 1 will be shown as 1.00. But because of it, i can't use default sort propely (sort doubles). Can I somehow change it, so when i push that button it will sort them as Double type?

[image]

Code here, if needed:

```
    import java.text.NumberFormat;
    import java.text.ParseException;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
    import javafx.geometry.Insets;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
    import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
    import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused") 
    public class Store_DateBase extends Application {

    Stage window;
    Scene scene;
    Button addButton, deleteButton;
    TableView<Store_Products> table;
    TextField nameInput, priceInput, quantityInput;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Store sortiment!");

        // name column
        TableColumn<Store_Products, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        nameColumn.setMinWidth(200);
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Store_Products, String>("name"));
        // price column
        TableColumn<Store_Products, String> priceColumn = new TableColumn<>("Price");
        priceColumn.setMinWidth(200);
        priceColumn.setStyle("-fx-alignment: CENTER;");
        priceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Store_Products, String>("price"));
        // Quantity column\
        TableColumn<Store_Products, Integer> intColumn = new TableColumn<>("Quantity");
        intColumn.setMinWidth(200);
        intColumn.setStyle("-fx-alignment: CENTER;");
        intColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Store_Products, Integer>("quantity"));

        // name inputs
        nameInput = new TextField();
        nameInput.setPromptText("Write a name");
        nameInput.setMinWidth(150);
        // price inputs
        priceInput = new TextField();
        priceInput.setPromptText("Write a price");
        priceInput.setMinWidth(100);
        //quantityInputs
        quantityInput = new TextField();
        quantityInput.setPromptText("Write a quantity");
        quantityInput.setMinWidth(100);

        // buttons
        addButton = new Button("Add");
        addButton.setOnAction(e -> addMeth());

        deleteButton = new Button("Delete");
        deleteButton.setOnAction(e -> deleteMeth());


        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        hBox.setSpacing(10);
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(nameInput, priceInput, quantityInput, addButton, deleteButton);

        table = new TableView<>();
        table.setItems(getProduct());
        table.getColumns().addAll(nameColumn, priceColumn, intColumn);

        VBox layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));
        layout.getChildren().addAll(table, hBox);

        scene = new Scene(layout);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }

    // delete button clicked
    private void deleteMeth() {
        ObservableList<Store_Products> productSelected, allProducts;
        allProducts = table.getItems();
        productSelected = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
        // for all products what are selected remove them from table.
        productSelected.forEach(allProducts::remove);
    }

    // add button clicked
    private void addMeth() {
        Store_Products produkts = new Store_Products();
        // get name
        produkts.setName(nameInput.getText());
        // get price
        double price = PriceValue(produkts);
        if (price != 0)
            produkts.setPrice(price);
        else
            return;
        // get quantity
        int quantity = QuantityValue(produkts);
        if (quantity != 0)
            produkts.setQuantity(quantity);
        else
            return;
        // add to the table
        table.getItems().add(produkts);
        // clear what is written after push "addButton"
        nameInput.clear();
        priceInput.clear();
        quantityInput.clear();
    }

    private double PriceValue(Store_Products price) {
        try {
            String value = priceInput.getText().replaceAll(",", ".");
            double doubleValue = Double.parseDouble(value);
            return doubleValue;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 0;
        }

    }

    private int QuantityValue(Store_Products quantity) {
        try {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(quantityInput.getText());
            return value;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 0;
        }

    }

    // get default products
    public ObservableList<Store_Products> getProduct() {
        ObservableList<Store_Products> products = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        products.add(new Store_Products("Laptop", 850.00, 27));
        products.add(new Store_Products("Desktop computer", 499.99, 66));
        products.add(new Store_Products("Proccesor", 50.00, 55));
        products.add(new Store_Products("Screen", 119.99, 22));
        products.add(new Store_Products("keyboard", 20.00, 270));
        products.add(new Store_Products("mouse", 16.99, 60));
        products.add(new Store_Products("mic", 5.90, 101));
        return products;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the column a `TableColumn<StoreProduct, Number>`, and use a cell factory to control the way it's displayed:

```
TableColumn<StoreProduct, Number> priceColumn = new TableColumn<>("Price");
// may need to update the properties in StoreProduct to have the correct type
// (but likely will be more convenient anyway)
priceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));
priceColumn.setCellFactory(tc -> new TableCell<StoreProduct, Number>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Number price, boolean empty) {
        if (empty) {
            setText("");
        } else {
            setText(String.format("%.2f", price.doubleValue()));
        }
    }
});
```

This would work with, e.g.

```
public class StoreProduct {

    private final DoubleProperty price = new SimpleDoubleProperty() ;

    public DoubleProperty priceProperty() {
        return price ;
    }

    public final double getPrice() {
        return priceProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setPrice(double price) {
        priceProperty().set(price);
    }

    // other properties...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed everything - works like a charm. :)

Comment: @EmilsP. Moral: never compromise your data representation for the sake of presentation. Always adapt the presentation to the data.